# Ruby on Rails is complaining about a method that doesn't exist that is built into Active Record. What?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am going over some basic guides in Rails, reviewing the basics
and such for an upcoming exam.  One of the guides included was the
sort-of-standard getting started guide over at guide.rubyonrails.org.
Here is the link if you need it.  Also all my code is for my app is
from there, so I have no problem releasing any of my code since it
should be the same as shown there.  I didn't do a copy paste, but I
basically was typing with Vim in one half of my screen and the web
page in the other half, typing what I see.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

So like I said, I am going along the guide when I noticed past a
certain point in the tutorial, I was always getting an error on the
site.  To find the section of code, just hit Ctrl+f on the page (or
whatever you have search/find set to) and enter "accepts_".  This
should immediately direct you to this chunk of code.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :title
  validates_length_of :title, :minimum => 5
  has_many :comments
  has_many :tags

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => :true  ,
   :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }
end
```

So I tried putting this in my code.  It is in
~/Rails/blog/app/models/post.rb in case you are wondering.  However,
even after all the other code I put in past that in the guide, hoping
I was just missing some line of code that would come up later in the
guide.  But nothing, same error every time.  This is what I get.

---

> ## NoMethodError in PostsController#index
>
> undefined method `accepts_nested_attributes_for' for #<Class:0xb7109f98>
>
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1833:in
>   `method_missing'
>   app/models/post.rb:7
>   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:9:in `index'
>
> ### Request
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> None
>
> ### Response
>
> #### Headers:
>
> {"Content-Type"=>"",
>    "cookie"=>[],
>    "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}

---

Now, I copied the above code from the guide.  The two code sections I
edited mentioned in the error message I will paste as is below.

---

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.xml

  before_filter :find_post,
    :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.find(:all) # <= the line 9 referred to in error message

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
    end
  end
```

---

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :title
  validates_length_of :title, :minimum => 5
  has_many :comments
  has_many :tags

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => :true  , # <= problem
    :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }
end
```

---

Also here is gem local gem list.  I do note that they are a bit out of date, but the default Rails install any of the school machines (an environment likely for my exam) is basically 'gem install rails --version 2.2.2' and since they are windows machines, they come with all the normal windows ruby gems that comes with the ruby installer.  However, I am running this off a Debian virtual machine of mine, but trying to set it up similarly and I figured the windows ruby gems wouldn't change anything in Rails.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.2.2)
actionpack (2.2.2)
activerecord (2.2.2)
activeresource (2.2.2)
activesupport (2.2.2)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
hpricot (0.8.2)
linecache (0.43)
log4r (1.1.7)
ptools (1.1.9)
rack (1.1.0)
rails (2.2.2)
rake (0.8.7)
sqlite3-ruby (1.2.3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look on http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for you'll see that accepts_nested_attributes_for only exists since Rails 2.3.2, so I'm afraid you won't have that functionality if you're running off of 2.2.

Comment: Thanks!  Also, if you don't me asking, can you possibly see any major drawbacks from just updating to the current stable?  The professor did mention we can declare a version of Rails so long as it is not Rails 3.  Just trying to figure out if I should just leave it at Rails 2.2.2 since that is the default setup on any school computer and just avoid stuff like that, update to 2.3.2 so I have the needed functionality to follow the guides used as references in the class, or just do a full update to whatever is the current stable version?

Comment: If you're just starting up, go with the latest version. Rails releases carry a lot of good stuff in them every time.

You can avoid dealing with issues with other computers not having the gem by doing a rake rails:freeze:gems, which will effectively copy the gems into your vendor/rails directory and use those instead of locally installed gems.

Comment: Nice to know about the gem freezing.  Thanks again! And thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You must upgrade to 2.3.2 or higher as [Antonio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821902/ruby-on-rails-is-complaining-about-a-method-that-doesnt-exist-that-is-built-into/2821955#2821955) suggests. I suggest using 2.3.5. You can either upgrade the gems on the system or freeze Rails to your application.

**To upgrade the gems**

```
gem install rails -v=2.3.5
```

**To freeze Rails**

```
cd /your/app/
git clone git://github.com/rails/rails vendor/rails
cd vendor/rails
git checkout v2.3.5
```